# Permission to DROP Tables in SQL Server (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

When running the DROP command (T-SQL) below on the SQL server the following message appears:

> Cannot drop the table '[dbo].[TABELA]', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

**Comand**

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DROP TABLE [?]'
```

However, when I run another T-SQL command or a basic DROP Table, the above error message is not displayed, and the command is executed correctly.

```
DROP TABLE TABELA
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all'
```

Both of the above commands work, what is the reason for the `EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DROP TABLE [?]'` Need a permission? and how to give this permission?

Comment: Your error and the table named in your SQL don't match. You can have different permissions again different objects. Perhaps you own `ArquivosFeiras` and so can drop it, but you don't own the table `dbo.TABELA`, nor to you have permission to `DROP` it; hence the error.

Comment: I think the error message is clear. Do you really have a table named `TABELA`? and if so do you have a `CONTROL` permission on the table? [See DROP TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#permissions).

Comment: @Sami I Change the name to put here

Comment: @Ricardo You say _"Both commands works"_ which mean `DROP TABLE TABELA` works and drop the table. So what's the problem? Do you want to drop an already dropped table?

Comment: Probable duplicate of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465296/t-sql-grant-permission-for-table-drop-and-create

Comment: @Sami I correct my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without the brackets. They seem to make the engine believe you want to drop a table *named* `[dbo].[tablea]` as `sp_MSForEachTable` already quotes if necessary. And of course a table named `[dbo].[tablea]` doesn't exist.

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DROP TABLE ?'
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e379b23f6aceb23a245d7f664d90433f)